# strncmp with too big of an n gives weird output

Tags: c, strncmp

I have 2 strings to compare, and I thought using `strncmp` would be better than using `strcmp` because I know one of the strings length.

```
char * a = "hel";
char * b = "he"; // in my real code this is scanned so it user dependent
for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("strncmp: %d\n", strncmp(a,b,i));
}
```

I expected the output to be

```
0
0
0
1   // which is the output of printf("strcmp: %d\n", strncmp(a,b));
1
```

since only in the 4th iteration (`i = 3`) the strings start to differ, but instead I got

```
0
0
0
108  // guessing this is due to 'l' == 108 in ascii
108
```

and I don't understand why, as **man** says:

> The `strcmp()` function compares the two strings s1 and s2. It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.
>
> The `strncmp()` function is similar, except it only compares the first (at most) n bytes of s1 and s2.

which means it should stop after reaching a `'\0'` and thus just returning 1 (like `strcmp`), wouldn't it?

Comment: *"When I run something like this on my embedded system, it crashes"* Code you have shown should not crash. You presumably did something different there.

Comment: When i is > 3 your are accessing  b out of bounds anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't think so, since the `NUL` terminator is still there.

Comment: @Angew you're right, it stops actually as soon as a NUL is encountered.

Comment: @user694733 I removed that part from the question (and found what went wrong there).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the quote you've posted:

> ... It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero ...

Both `1` and `108` are integers greater than 0. There's no guarantee the function has to return `1` or `-1`.

Comment: However, how is it that `strcmp` implementation differs from `strncmp` in the return value? it is very weird

Comment: @CIsForCookies What's so weird about it? The functions do different things, and since these low-level routines are quite likely super-optimised, they can be implemented *very* differently.

Comment: Ah, well I naively thought they would just add a condition in the for loop or something, but I guess you are right. Thanks!

Comment: Angew, why is the third compare 0 (equal)? The second string is length 2 and the first 3, so comparing 3 chars should say "string 1 is larger"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Notice the loop starts from 0, so the 3rd comparison is comparing 2 characters.

Comment: Ah...yes..the first compares 0 chars, which is equal :-)